# When importing elements from Selenium writes to multiple lines on CSV instead of one

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, selenium

I can pull the code and it writes to the CSV but when imported to excel only the first line of the html shows in the excel file. It does work properly in Google Sheets. I am sure an imported line break is in there but I do not know how to strip it before writing to CSV. Thanks for any and all help.

My code.

```
def grabAddress():
    element = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="memberDetail"]/section/div/div[1]/div[3]/p[2]/strong')

    strings = []
    for x in element:
        strings.append(x.text)
    splitstrings = "".join(strings)
    address.append(splitstrings)
    return 0

with open(r"C:\bnicsv\compiled.csv", "w", newline ="") as compiledCSV:
    writecompiledtoCSV = csv.writer(compiledCSV, delimiter=",")
    writecompiledtoCSV.writerows(compiled_list)
```

HTML I am pulling...

```
<strong>
        Jack Jackson<br>
        Jacks Jewelers<br>
        1985 East End Blvd.<br>
        St. Paul Park, MN 55555                        
</strong>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the CSV is being written correctly, but when you open it in Excel, Excel shows just the first line of the CSV and not the others?

Comment: @WillKeeling Yes. If I open in google sheets the info is there. If I open in notepad the info is there but excel will only show first line. so in this html example it shows Jack Jackson.

Comment: Try manually increasing the height of the row in Excel.